# Linear regression on percentages?

Tags: r, regression, econometrics, percentage

I am trying to formulate a model through simple linear regression of automobile sales dependent on GDP growth.

I have the following data:

1. Annual GDP growth in the affected countries as a percentage
2. Annual automobile sales in both growth percentage and absolute numbers.

My question is:

Can I get a logically sound result from simply regressing sales percentage increase ~ GDP percentage growth?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it makes perfect sense.
It would be the answer to the question, "Does the auto industry grow/shrink as the GDP grows/shrinks?"
You may even find that as the GDP increases, the auto industry decreases - who knows!

But you can answer other questions by looking at your other data; it all depends on the conclusions you are interested in.

If you have the actual GDP value in a given year, you can calculate the yearly GDP values using the percentage-growth stats and regress the number of auto sales against the GDP.